# Using Raster Bender plugin to rubbersheet raster layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, rubbersheeting

I have a distorted raster of a historic map that I need to warp to match the modern map.

I've installed the plugin Raster Bender into QGIS 2.18, but I can't work out how to use it, and can find no instructions online.

How do I set up the pairs of points for it to use to warp the raster?

If there is an alternative method for QGIS 3, that would do. I have both versions.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/olivierdalang/RasterBender "Raster Bender by Olivier Dalang on GitHub") you will find the official guide on how to use it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155703)